# SQL displaying both records found and not found in items orders

Tags: sql, oracle

My task is to display customers that have and have not ordered a specific item in the same results. My tables joined on CustomerNumber:

```
Customers Table:

CustomerNumber    CustomerName
-------------     ------------
1007              H&G Groceries
2548              Jims Restaurant
2005              Tangs Asian Foods


Orders Table:

CustomerNumber    ItemNumber    ItemDescripton    NumberOrdered
--------------    ----------    --------------    -------------
1007              2055          Cheese            3
2548              8784          Canned Beans      6
2005              1199          Dozen Large Eggs  10
```

If I were to request the purchasing history of **ItemNumber=2055**

This is the way I would like to display the results. Now keep in mind all customers are in the Orders table for one item at least once

```
CustomerName     ItemNumber    ItemDescription  NumberOrdered
------------     ----------    ---------------  -------------

H&G Groceries    2055          Cheese           3
Jims Restaurant                                 0
Tangs Asian Food                                0
```

Actually NumberOrder could just be blank and not necessary have a 0

This is what I have tried.

```
    Select c.CustomerName,

    o.ItemNumber,

    o.ItemDescription,

    o.NumberOrdered

    From Customers C

    Left Join Orders o ON c.CustomerNumber = o.CustomerNumber

    Where o.OrderNumber = 2055;
```

This only returns the one record for H&G Groceries.

Comment: Isn't this what LEFT JOIN is all about? What's the problem?

Comment: You need a [left outer join](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa178429(v=SQL.80).aspx) to do this.

Comment: Also post what you have tried, not just what you need.

Comment: Here's a link for [Oracle](http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_left_outer_join.htm).

Comment: Im a beginner and a student. Please dont be so harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Where o.OrderNumber = 2055
    or o.OrderNumber is null
```

You have to account for nulls in the `WHERE` clause when you're working with outer joins.

Alternately, you could put the condition in the `JOIN` condition:

```
Select c.CustomerName,
    o.ItemNumber,
    o.ItemDescription,
    o.NumberOrdered
From Customers C
Left Join Orders o 
    On c.CustomerNumber = o.CustomerNumber
    And o.OrderNumber = 2055;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use a left outer join. i.e.

Select * from CustomersTable 
LEFT JOIN OrdersTable on CustomerTable.CustomerNumber = OrdersTable.CustomerNumber

Comment: David Im thinking I need to add a WHERE clause for OrderNumber 2055 but when I do, my results only have the one record for H&G Groceries.